# How to delete all list elements matching a regexp?

Tags: list

Given a list:

```
(setq mylist '("a1" "a2" "b1" "b2"))
```

How to delete all elements that match `^a`?

What I want is `"a1"` and `"a2"` deleted, only left `"b1"` and `"b2"` in the list.

Comment: Note that "alist" is lisp terminology meaning "association list", which is a very specific kind of structure.  I've edited the code to eliminate that confusion.

Comment: Note also that `^` matches beginning-of-line, not beginning-of-string; see [`(elisp) Syntax of Regexps`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) for how to do the latter, which is probably what you want here.

Comment: @Drew Ah, we're at editing cross-purposes here.  I've been removing references to `alist` (because there was none -- I honestly thought it was probably a contraction of "a list" which was written without knowledge of association lists).  You've been adding them, though :)  AFAICS the question isn't actually about alists.

Comment: @phils: Sorry; my bad. You're right, of course. The question is not about alists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you want a new list that has only elements `"b1"` and `"b2"`? Or do you want the same list structure, but modified to have removed elements `"a1"` and `"a2"`?

@rpluim shows one way to do the former. A similar way to do the latter is to use `cl-delete-if` instead of `cl-remove-if`.

```
(setq mylist  (cl-delete-if (lambda (k) (string-match-p "^a" k)) mylist)
```

(Make sure you set variable `mylist` to the result returned by `cl-delete-if`, if you expect that variable's value to reflect the deletion properly in all cases. See the Elisp manual, node [Rearrangement](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Rearrangement.html) for more about this.)

Comment: My name has an `i` in it, but single-character edits are not allowed. *sigh*

Comment: @rpluim: Sorry 'bout that; corrected.

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do this, here's one:

```
(setq mylist (cl-remove-if (lambda (k)
                            (string-match "^a" k))
                          mylist)
```